# Why am I asked to add 3 projects to my Stack Overflow CV?

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow-jobs

I have a problem with the CV improvement functionality on Stack Overflow. I have Completion Score of 94%.

And one of two improvement suggestions is "Add 3 projects". I get this suggestion from the very beginning, ignoring the fact that I already added more than 6 open source projects:

https://stackoverflow.com/cv/gevorg

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug?

**Updates**

1. After completing another improvement which is `link stack exchange account with 200 reputation`, my completion score is the same 94% and "Add 3 projects" is now the only improvement suggestion.
2. Now I am on 98% and there are no improvement suggestions :)

Comment: Related: my completion score is at 80% but I don't see any improvement or suggestions.  Where are you seeing these?

Comment: On top right corner on edit CV.

Comment: Not for me, unless I'm looking in the wrong place: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Lowda.png  I don't see anything but "Preview" and "Settings"

Comment: Yes I see suggestions in the middle of preview and settings.

Comment: Hmm, weird.  Maybe that's a bug for me?  Depending on the answer to your question, I might ask a separate question about where my cv improvement suggestions went.

Comment: It tells me to add names to the projects as a suggestion from 90% even though I've done that.

Comment: // , Question NOT the robot completionism chaperones!

Comment: Maybe a tiny little bit offtopic, but you know you can use vim on windows too, right?

Comment: @Matty but Windows' builtin PTY interface is awful and not fun to program or use, and cmd.exe is pure hell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CVs are no more, they have been migrated to developer stories, which work a bit differently now.

Marking this one as [status-norepro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status-norepro).