# How do I get the last 2% of my completion score?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I think I've filled everything in on my <strike>careers</strike> jobs [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/cv/georgeduckett), but apparently there's 2% more I could fill in:

[image: Completion score at 98%]

What am I missing?

P.S. I may have filled in a couple of things with placeholders to rule them out of the 2%, can you guess where?

Comment: I haven't filled one in so I don't know all of the available fields but maybe t is looking for more associated content.  Is there a space to link to your website/blog or github page?

Comment: The website i've put as my linkedin profile, the blog I put as example.org. I filled in github too, but they've not fetched the data yet so that's not showing.

Comment: I guess you can do nothing here, look  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322439/972240, I failed to do so too (same 98% now). Also I noticed that percent randomly changes from time to time.

Comment: It'll be 100% when you retire.

Comment: It's an evil plot to punish all the OCD folks...

Comment: @JeffC That's why I made it go back to 50%, so it's a more satisfying number. Optimists would say my profile is half-complete, while pessimists would say my profile is half-empty.

Comment: @Gert I didn't realise I was this close to retirement! Not sure if that's a good thing or a bad thing...

Comment: 100% completion is probably reserved for Jon Skeet